# Add HTML Id's to tags in .aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, file-io

So I'm writing an app that lets the user select a folder, it gets all the .aspx files in that folder, and lets the users check off which ones they want to add HTML ID's to.

Then they click start, and this runs

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
            {

            }
        }
```

It loops through all the selected file names. How do I open each of these .aspx files in the background, and go through them and add the

```
id="thisItemId"
```

attribute to each tag that's like a , , , , , etc....

Comment: something very simple. like the name of the tag so say like...if it ran into the first <td> tag it would call it td1, etc...

Comment: That sounds like a dumb idea.  What's the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know how to do basic file IO, I recommend using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the ASPX files. Using that library you can modify the HTML elements in which you're interested, and then save the file back using some more basic file IO.

Answer (score 0):

[LinqToHTML](http://www.justagile.com/linq-to-html.aspx) will do the job.

Comment: How would I do this though? Like I want to open up an .aspx from a directory, just add attributes to SPECIFIC tags, and then resave it.